# How to evaluate the quality / trustworthiness of textual information?

Tags: nlp

I have a corpus of text (which can be used for learning). The text consists of proper names like street names:

```
Bond Street
Balmain Crescent
Parkes Way
Barrine Drive
Gordon Street
Marcuse Clarke Street
```

I want to detect possible spelling errors (i.e. evaluate the quality / trustworthiness of some text such as street names).

The idea is that a sequence of strings can be evaluated based on the likelyhood that certain strings occur in a certain order (I suppose [sequence-to-sequence](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/lstm_seq2seq/) models and [markov chain](https://github.com/jsvine/markovify) models strongly draw from this idea).

Thus even if a sequence such as `Marcuse Clarke Street` may occur seldom, the observed sequences of strings such as `Cla, lar, ark, rke` may occur more often than (assuming a spelling error like `Marcuse Cqarke Street`) `Cqa, qar, ark, rke`.

**Question:** Are there models to estimate the probability that some sequence of strings is "true" given some training data? My objective would be:

Input: `Street` -> Model output: `very likely` (high probability that it may occur)

Input: `Stxeet` -> Model output: `very unlikely` (low probability...)

Input: `Balmain` -> Model output: `likely` (OK probability that it may occur)

Input: `Buwmain` -> Model output: `unlikely` (low probability...)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you want/ can do, have a look at the [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) in some systems it is implemented as "Edit-Distance".

Comment: This will only indicate the distance between two entries. However, I don't see how this may indicate a spelling error since you would need to know the exact "ground thruth", namely that "Balmain" is true and "Buwain" is the (corresponding) candidate to be compared to this truth.

Comment: So your question is rather how do you create a truthworthy dictionary from the corpus. It sounded like you had a corpus of proper names (thought this meant valid proper names) already to compare with. Apart from counting how often a word or sylable occures and creating something like a bayesian heuristic, I am not aware of any other method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any specific method/library, but I work a lot with large pre-trained transformer models and you can definitely calculate the probability that a token or series of tokens will occur according to a model that has trained on a lot of text.

[Here is a SO post showing how to do exactly that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70299442/how-to-get-a-probability-distribution-over-tokens-in-a-huggingface-model)

Now that will only get you the probabilities from some pre-trained model of your choice, I imagine the next thing you would want to do is find some intelligent way of classifying whether or not it is a valid entry based on those probabilities.

You might be able to just kind of eyeball it, but if you find that isn't working I would recommend adding a prompt to help it understand the task that it's trying to do.

Or you could just label a bunch of examples and fine tune a model as well, I would recommend looking at [Pattern Exploit Training (PET)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.07676.pdf) as an option to avoid some large labeling task, [here is the github](https://github.com/timoschick/pet).

There is another version of PET called "[ADAPET](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.11955.pdf)" that tries to improve upon PET, in my experience it's a bit finicky & prone to overfitting depending on the task, but I think the way the losses are setup it actually might be a really good fit for what you're trying to do, so also worth checking that out, [here is the github](https://github.com/rrmenon10/ADAPET).